# Laravel eloquent retrieve data through multiple many to many tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table structure:

`members`

`merchandise_categories`

`member_merchandise_categories` // many to many to join the 2 above tables

Then I also have:

`brands`

`brand_merchandise_categories` // many to many to join brands and merchandise categories

I want to get all the brands associated with a member.

So a member is associated with a `merchandise_category` through `member_merchandise_categories` which has a `member_id` and a then the `merchandise_category` is linked to a `brand` through `brand_merchandise_categories`

Ideally I want to end up with a flat collection of brands for a given member. How do I do this in Laravel?

Here are some of my relationhips definded:

**Member**

```
public function merchandise_categories()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            MerchandiseCategory::class,
            MemberMerchandiseCategory::class,
            'member_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'merchandise_category_id'
        );
    }


    public function member_merchandise_categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MemberMerchandiseCategory::class);
    }
```

**MerchandiseCategory**

```
public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class, 'member_merchandise_categories');
    }

    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class);
    }
```

**BrandMerchandiseCategory**

```
public function merchandise_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(MerchandiseCategory::class);
    }
```

**Brand**

```
public function merchandise_categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MerchandiseCategory::class);
    }

    public function brand_merchandise_categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BrandMerchandiseCategory::class, 'brand_id', 'id');
    }
```

Here is what I have started with:

```
$member = Member::where('id', Auth::user()->member_id)->with('member_merchandise_categories.merchandise_category.brands')->first();

             $brands = collect();
             foreach ($member->merchandise_categories as $cat) {
                 foreach ($cat->brands as $brand) {
                  
                     $brands->push($brand);
                 }
             }
```

This gives me a collection of brands but I'm not sure this is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Your model relations have some problems, it better using camel case naming, and you are misusing `hasManyThrough` method.

Since you have a pivot table, it has directly relation, directly relation should use `belongsToMany()` instead of `hasManyThrough()`.

And your there is no directly relation (pivot table) between your `Member` and `Brand`, this is where you should use the `hasManyThrough()`.

## Answer

Assuming your foreign key naming convention matches what Laravel expects.

#### Member

```php
class Member extends Model
{
    public function memberMerchandiseCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MemberMerchandiseCategory::class);
    }

    public function merchandiseCategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MerchandiseCategory::class, MemberMerchandiseCategory::class);
    }

    // This is where you need to use hasManyThrough.
    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Brand::class, MerchandiseCategory::class);
    }
}
```

#### MemberMerchandiseCategory

If this is a prune pivot table without any data, which means it's all foreign id on it, then suggest extends the `Pivot` class.

You can create the pivot model by `php artisan make:model --pivot`.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class MemberMerchandiseCategory extends Pivot
{
    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class);
    }

    public function merchandiseCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(MerchandiseCategory::class);
    }
}
```

#### MerchandiseCategory

```php
class MerchandiseCategory extends Model
{
    public function memberMerchandiseCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MemberMerchandiseCategory::class);
    }

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class, MemberMerchandiseCategory::class);
    }

    public function brandMerchandiseCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BrandMerchandiseCategory::class);
    }

    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, BrandMerchandiseCategory::class);
    }
}
```

#### BrandMerchandiseCategory

This model should extends `Pivot` too.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class BrandMerchandiseCategory extends Pivot
{
    public function merchandiseCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(MerchandiseCategory::class);
    }

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

#### Brand

```php
class Brand extends Model
{
    public function brandMerchandiseCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BrandMerchandiseCategory::class);
    }

    public function merchandiseCategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MerchandiseCategory::class, BrandMerchandiseCategory::class)
    }
}
```

This answer is not tested, but if there is all good, you should able to use `Member::find(1)->brands();` get all brands from a member.